# Uniformly pick a sphere's center...

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry

Let's pick the point of the center of a sphere on a 3-d axis the $x$ coordinate, $y$ coordinate, and $z$ coordinate of the sphere's center, $(x, y, z)$ are each separately from a uniform distribution $[0, 1] $

From these coordinates, we make a sphere with radius $1$.

What is the percent of the surface area (on average) that lies within the cube region with vertices at:

$(0,0,1), (1,0,1), (0,1,1), (1,1,1),$

$(0,0,2), (1,0,2), (0,1,2), (1,1,2)$

So my first thought was to just assume that $x,y,z$ are each $0.5$ since that is the expected value of each (or the average) and then calculate it from there, but I know that that logic is flawed because of monte carlo simulations- although I can't figure out why.

Also, I know that the absolute upper bound would be $1/6$ as the percent of the surface area that is in the cube region above it's center on average should be the same percent of the surface area that is in the cube region below and likewise the the $4$ around it as well by symmetry. It cannot equal $1/6$ because some of the non orthagonally adjacent cube regions will have some of the surface area in them.

Comment: Have you done the 2D problem as a warm-up?

Comment: There seems to be some confusion in how the problem is stated.  Do you mean the x coordinate, y coordinate and z coordinate of the sphere's center, (x, y, z) are each separately from a uniform distribution [0, 1] ?

This is not to be nitpicky.  However, I've seen problems which seem to simply be misstated, but in reality there a much deeper interpretation intended if I assumed it was simply misstated.  A point is a not a coordinate and a coordinate is not a point, but the first three paragraphs seems to confuse a coordinate with a point.

Comment: @nickalh I meant: the x coordinate, y coordinate and z coordinate of the sphere's center, (x, y, z) are each separately from a uniform distribution [0, 1]

Comment: @TedShifrin well the part that I'm tripped up on dealing with even the 2D problem, is that I don't know what to do with the part where the center is not at a fixed point. Like obviously if I know where the center of the circle (2D now) is, I can calculate the percent of the circumference that is in the square region above it, but I'm lost as to what to do when the center of this circle can vary.

Comment: If you can figure out the answer for an arbitrary fixed center... call it $p(x,y,z)$... then the expected answer is $\int_{0}^{1}dx \int_{0}^{1}dy \int_{0}^{1}dz \; p(x,y,z).$  This isn't necessarily the same as $p(1/2, 1/2, 1/2)$, as you've noticed (unless $p$ happens to be a linear function of its arguments).

Comment: Ditto for the 2D case (with a two-dimensional integral instead).

Comment: It seems to me that the maximum fraction is $1/8$, which is what we get when the center is at one of the four points $z=1$, $x,y\in\{0,1\}$, and one octant of the sphere sits snugly within the cube. For other choice of the center the fraction is lower, going down to zero when the center of the sphere slides down to $z=0$. Therefore the average is sure lower than $1/8$.

Comment: For reasons of symmetry we can restrict ourselves to cases $x,y\in[0,1/2]$. IOW, in terms of the function $p(x,y,z)$ introduced by mjqxxxx we have $$p(x,y,z)=p(1-x,y,z)=p(x,1-y,z)=p(1-x,1-y,z)$$ for all $x,y,z$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of *an expected value* from probability? That is what *the average* suggests, right? In (multivariable) we can also think of the average without probabilities. As in the average height of a plane region, or the average height of a 3D object. But it comes to much the same thing (except here we have more dimensions).